# Invalid URL for SOFU+ error pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks

If you land on any of the main SOFU error pages (e.g. `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/`) including some of the Stack Exchange beta sites (e.g. `http://gaming.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/`), the URLs being generated are missing the colon after `http`.

This causes the browsers to try to go to `http://http//meta.stackoverflow.com`.

I have tested and verified this error in Chrome 6 dev, IE8, and Firefox 3.6.

Comment: While we're at it, Meta's not coming up with a list of possible duplicates for questions... I posted about the same problem without this page (or any others for that matter) being reported to me as possible duplicates first.  I deleted my question after noticing someone posted a link to this one as a comment.

Comment: when i viewed source, the link is actually `http://http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com`

Comment: @R.Bemrose Part of that can be blamed on the fact that not one of the >5 reports of this issue have used similar titles and wording.

Comment: @Grace Note: Yeah, I was kind of worried about that - I didn't quite know what to put, since it seems that the base template is affected. I didn't want to tie it to just one site since it's almost all of them.

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed, with addendum: this is just the link in the text of the page. The tabs and header links work just fine.